# Teradata to Oracle Query eaxdata Conversion

Tags: oracle, teradata

I need help with converting the below SQL query in Taradata to Oracle exadata. Not sure how to convert the date, I changed the CAST date function To_Date but get a few errors.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        pat.pat_id,
        pat.pat_mrn_id AS patientmrn,
        pat.pat_name   AS patientname,
        adt_pat_class_c,
        pat.death_date AS deathdate,
        cast(patenc.hosp_admsn_time AS DATE format 'mm/dd/yyyy') AS          
        admitdate,
        cast(patenc.hosp_disch_time AS DATE format 'mm/dd/yyyy') AS 
        dischargedate,
        extract(year FROM acct.adm_date_time)-extract(year FROM 
        pat.birth_date) - CASE WHEN acct.adm_date_time (format 
        'MMDD')CHAR(4)) 
        <pat.birth_date (format 'MMDD') (CHAR(4)) THEN 1 ELSE 0               
        END AS patage,
            adt_billing_type_c,
            adt_patient_stat_c,
            hosp_admsn_type_c,
            acct_basecls_ha_c,
            ordproc.order_proc_id AS order_id,
            ordproc.ordering_date
FROM  patient pat
inner join pat_enc_hsp patenc ON pat.pat_id = patenc.pat_id
inner join hsp_account acct ON acct.prim_enc_csn_id = patenc.pat_enc_csn_id
inner join order_proc ordproc ON acct.prim_enc_csn_id ON 
ordproc.pat_enc_csn_id
inner join clarity_ser ser ON ser.prov_id = ordproc.authrzing_prov_id
inner join identity_ser_id idser ON ser.prov_id=idser.prov_id 
inner join clarity_loc loc ON loc.loc_id = acct.loc_id
inner join zc_loc_rpt_grp_7 grp7 ON loc.rpt_grp_seven = grp7.rpt_grp_seven
WHERE grp7.name = 'AB'
AND cast(patenc.hosp_disch_time AS DATE format 'mm/dd/yyyy') >= '01/01/2019'
AND admit_conf_stat_c IN (1,4)
AND description LIKE '%CULTURE%'
AND ordproc.lab_status_c = 3
AND adt_pat_class_c IN ('1204','12113')
AND result_time > patenc.hosp_disch_time;
```

I changed the top part of the query(one with dates) -

```
select distinct
   pat.pat_id,
   pat.PAT_MRN_ID as PatientMRN,
   pat.PAT_NAME as PatientName,
   ADT_PAT_CLASS_C,
   pat.DEATH_DATE as DeathDate,
   TO_DATE(patenc.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as AdmitDate,
   TO_DATE(patenc.HOSP_DISCH_TIME, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as DischargeDate----
```

I get the below errors - 
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P02G, instance nzcladb01xm.nndc.kp.org:CDB001N41 (1)
ORA-01843: not a valid month
12801. 00000 -  "error signaled in parallel query server %s"
*Cause:    A parallel query server reached an exception condition.
*Action:   Check the following error message for the cause, and consult
           your error manual for the appropriate action.
*Comment:  This error can be turned off with event 10397, in which
           case the server's actual error is signaled instead.

Comment: What errors did you get? And what query have you managed to get so far?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I am getting the below errors - ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P02G, instance nzcladb01xm.nndc.kp.org:CDB001N41 (1)
ORA-01843: not a valid month
12801. 00000 -  "error signaled in parallel query server %s"
*Cause:    A parallel query server reached an exception condition.
*Action:   Check the following error message for the cause, and consult
           your error manual for the appropriate action.
*Comment:  This error can be turned off with event 10397, in which
           case the server's actual error is signaled instead.

Comment: I changed the top part of the query (one with dates) -select distinct
   pat.pat_id,
 pat.PAT_MRN_ID as PatientMRN,
 pat.PAT_NAME as PatientName,
 ADT_PAT_CLASS_C,
 pat.DEATH_DATE as DeathDate,
 TO_DATE(patenc.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as AdmitDate,
 TO_DATE(patenc.HOSP_DISCH_TIME, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as DischargeDate,

Comment: There's definitely a mismatch between the column value and the date format, as error 'ORA-01843: not a valid month' states. Please, check one more time values in the table and if they all match the given format. Also, you have date conversion in your 'where' clause and extraction on the select columns list. Check them out as well, remove these conversions and try running your query again.

Comment: There's another part involving date calculation, `patage`, it's a strange age calculation, in Oracle probably `trunc(months_between(acct.adm_date_time, pat.birth_date))`

Comment: Thank you both. Yes the date values do not match (it's in DD-MM-YY format)